# NullPointerException after returning value using enum

Tags: java, android, android-room

My converter class:

```
public class CategoriesConverter extends Item_get {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Item_get.Food_type toFood_type(int food_type){
        if(food_type == SWEETS.getCode()){
            return SWEETS;
        }else if(food_type == DRINKS.getCode()){
            return DRINKS;
        }else if(food_type == OTHER.getCode()){
            return OTHER;
        }else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error Status");
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static int toInt(Item_get.Food_type food_type){
        return food_type.getCode();
    }
}
```

In my `Recyclerview` When I click edit image I put to the next activity data like that:

```
@Override
public void onEditClick(Item_get item_get) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Delete_details.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY1", item_get);
    intent.putExtra(Edit_Delete_details.EXTRA_ID, item_get.getId());
    start_next_activity.launch(intent);
}
```

In second activity I am doing it like this:

```
intent = getIntent();
item_get = intent.getParcelableExtra("KEY1");
id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, default: -1);
name = item_get.getName_Product();
amount = item_get.getAmount();
Item_get.Food_type food_type = item_get.food_type.getCode();
```

Line above with `food_type` always return `null` and I don't know why, because in first activity something like this works good:

```
String f = String.valueOf(item_get.food_type); <-- Return String representation of enum like: SWEETS
OR 
int n = item_get.food_type.getCode(); <-- Return integer of actually selected enum category like: 1
```

When I do it like below:

```
int n = item_get.food_type.getCode();
intent.putExtra("LINK", n);
```

it works good. I have it in activity 2.

But why I can't send it with whole item_get object? Like it is with Name Product and Amount, instead of this I must put it to the second variable?

Problem is when I want send back data from activity 2 to activity 1 I am getting error like this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.project.Item_get$Food_type.getCode()' on a null object reference

When I change in CategoriesConverter class:

```
@TypeConverter
public static int toInt(Item_get.Food_type food_type){
    From
    return food_type.getCode();
    to
    return 1;
}
```

Error does not occur (this is not a solution) but maybe it is a tip.

My Item_get.class has **enum** like this:

```
public enum Food_type{
    SWEETS(1),
    DRINKS(2),
    OTHER(3);
    private int code;
    Food_type(int code){
        this.code = code;
    }
    public int getCode(){
        return code;
    }
}
```

Also I added `@TypeConverters` in database.
I have read that enum are parcelabe objects.
I am using `RoomDatabase`
So why I am getting null object after changing from activity 1 to activity 2?

Comment: Please add the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I don't think enums are parcelable but are serializable. You can make them parcelable, though, by implementing the interface.

I personally would add the code as the intent extra, and read it back on the other side. It's a small payload,  and you don't have to implement parcelable.